# Is it possible to rename fields in firestore collection?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am new to Cloud Firestore in Firebase. In my project I have created collections but I need to rename field names for each collection. Is it possible? Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Is it possible to rename fields in firestore collection?

No, it's not, there is no API for doing that. In Firestore it's not possible to change the names of your properties once you have created them. All that fields are immutable.

A workaround would be to read your documents, make the necessary changes and then put it all back in with the new property names.

Answer (score 10):

I wrote few helpers for firestore: https://github.com/39ro/fireboost

One of those include renaming a field for a document

```js
const docRef = db.collection('users').doc('xyz');
const utilDocRef = fireBoostFirestore.ref(docRef)

utilDocRef.renameField({oldFieldKey: 'newFieldKey'})
```

or for all documents in a collection

```js
const colRef = db.collection('users');
const utilColRef = fireBoostFirestore.ref(colRef);

utilColRef.renameFieldDocs({oldFieldKey: 'newFieldKey'})
```

Hope it can help someone!

Answer (score 1):

No, you have to write the function yourself, maybe create your own admin panel to do these actions.

I use https://firefoo.app/ for this and other small things.  I will need to create my own admin panel one day but this is good for updating field names, exporting collections etc.

Comment: thanks for that tipp. that app is brilliant

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way:

1. get the document, read the old field
2. update the document putting the value in the new field
3. delete the old field (on the same update function)

```
const thingsQuery = await db.collection('things').get()
        
thingsQuery.forEach(thing => {
  if (thing.data().oldName) {
    db.collection('things').doc(thing.id).update({
      newName: thing.data().oldName,
      oldName: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.delete()
    })
  }
})
```