# Update field key in cloud firestore

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Updating a field can be done like

```
firestore.collection("Users").document(user).update("key", "value");
```

but i want to do the opposite. updating "key" itself. not it's value. for example `key: value ---> key2: value`

Is it possible?

Thanks

Comment: No, it's not possible. Please check the [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57003980/is-it-possible-to-rename-fields-in-firestore-collection/57004064#57004064).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are asking is not possible. But you can achieve this by getting the value first by the key, then store the value in a variable. After that you can add a new record. So the value will be same, but key will be updated.
I hope you understood what I'm trying to say.

Comment: This is the right approach.  Just make sure you do this [inside a transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions) which will protect you from other changes happening at the same time.  The transaction would need to do an update that both deletes the current key and adds the new key.